# ASP.NET web control with the same ID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

On an ASP.NET page, if the ASP.NET elements like `<asp:Texbox ID="Textbox1">` appears in more than one place, are they the same Textbox object or are they different objects with the same name "Textbox1"? If the same, "why won't it cause any conflicts?"

E.G.

```
<asp:DetailsView 
        ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    **<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"** runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    **<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"** runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <span class="style6">
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="A"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </span>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField CancelText="" ShowInsertButton="True" ValidationGroup="A" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: What is that E.G. Line supposed to be?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I seem to have got the idea. I did not explain my question clearly.Basically I had a gridview and a detailsview control on the same page, each of them has a template field which contains a textbox, with identical ID "textbox1".My understanding now is the two textbox objects are declared inside the gridview object and detailsview objects respectively, so they can have the same name without comflicts. BTW it seems hard to post code on SO with `<>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring textbox controls inside other controls e.g. gridview control is declaring inside the object of the containning control, ie no longer declaring inside the aspx page object. Therefore the name can be identical.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to [Naming Containers](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx) with regards to databound controls. If you've got a TextBox inside of a repeater, basically they'll render like this:

```
<input name="Repeater1$ctl00$TextBox1" type="text" value="Text on row" id="Repeater1_ctl00_TextBox1" />
<input name="Repeater1$ctl01$TextBox1" type="text" value="Text on row" id="Repeater1_ctl01_TextBox1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your update.

If you declare controls (textboxes) inside a `GridView` or any other control that allows nested controls then the ASP.NET engine actually creates a unique ID for it (something like ctl00_main_ddlCtrl). From ASP.NET 4.0 you can control what IDs it creates, it previous versions you cannot.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. My question was really if `<asp:Texbox ID="Textbox1">` appears in more than one place in an aspx page, are they the same object or different objects in separate "domains" so that they can have the same object identifier without causing conflict? My guess is they are not the same object, but I'd like to know a bit more underlying principle

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour of such elements depends on the browser. In HTML specification is a requirement that an ID must be unique. Thus even though the browser will accept such a page, the behaviour might be a little off. Usually, no element would respond to a non-unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that they aren't objects at all the way you have declared them.

```
<asp:Textbox Id="TextBox1">SOMETEXT</asp:textbox>
<asp:Textbox Id="TextBox1">SOMETEXT2</asp:textbox>
```

They are only html tags with the same id property. Look at the source of the web page and you will see that they are just rendered as text b/c the browser doesn't know what to do w/  tags.  Instead of converting them to inputs.  Without the Runat="server" tag, the compiler will not convert them to html with generated Id tags, also they will not be available to access in the code behind.

When you add the runat="server" tag you will be forced to change the Id properties to be unique names b/c they except in the same context and therefore cannot have the same ids.

Basically the short answer is, if you see `<asp:textbox...` when you view source through your browser, you have not declared your textboxes properly. Instead you should see `<input ...`

Comment: Hi mate, the problem is SO does not seem to allow easy posting of large chunks of code, so I can't let you see the full picture...